# Wheres my workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online

I created a workflow in SharePoint Designer, for the Document Library Costs. Now when I go to costs on SharePoint Online.

Under Library, Workflow Settings.

It does not show the workflow associated with the list.

Why is that?

Also if I go to lists and libraries in share-point designer then go to my Costs Library and I click new workflow. Then create one, it does not show up there either. Why does it not show up in workflows associated with this list?

Comment: Just to verify I got this right, going to the Library > Settings > Workflow Settings does not display the workflow, but going to the Library > Document > Workflows shows the workflow under the 'Start a new Workflow' section?

Comment: Its not showing up in either places.... corrected my question to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Can you verify the workflow was published and not just saved?

Comment: What do you mean you created one from Microsoft Online? To verify it's published, simply republish it.

Comment: If I create one from Share Point Online it shows up. Although not from ones created in SP Designer. How would I verify these. In workflows in designer it shows created date. Is that verified

Comment: Why does a workflow created using SP Online not show up in Workflows in SP Designer?

Comment: Solved I didnt realized it had to be published

Comment: I have seen a similar issue where (for whatever reason) publishing a workflow to SharePoint under the 2013 engine doesn't work. You have to publish it using the 2010 engine.